# what conditions are needed to install Docker DTR on a node, how do I test for them?

Tags: docker

In my orchestration installing docker dtr I am running into issues with nodes not being ready for me to run `docker run .... dtr (install|join)...`

I am confirming that both ucp containers are on the node but sometimes its not enough and I am getting the error.

> DEBU[0007] failed to create container: Error response from daemon: Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions [available container slots]

I know that this means that the ucp membership is not 100% but I don't know how to confirm further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well folks I found the answer.

I have 2 checks that I am running in a loop.

**Checking that ucp is running on the node**

`docker ps --filter status=running | grep ucp | wc -l`

Should return `2`

**Are Docker UCP containers completely processed on the node?**

The *ucp-reconcile* container will run and then exit when UCP it totally done. If it exits any thing but 0 it will be failed.

`docker ps -a --filter \'exited=0\' | grep ucp-reconcile | wc -l')`

This should return `1`